# Is there a way to load pages/site from specific referring source only?

Tags: private

I am trying to create a user manual for our software which would be stored on WordPress.  But I don't want it accessible to just anyone, it should be hidden, at the very least not indexed by search engines.  I know how to set pages not to be indexed so that they are "private".

But is there a way to take it a step further and have the pages ONLY load if they are referred by the software? So let's say a user is in one of our modules and there's a Help button, they click on it and it takes them to the right page on WP.  But WP checks to see where the link came from and if it came from the software it will display, otherwise not.

That would be the best case scenario, any ideas if this is achievable?

Comment: If I may be so bold, I think you have come to this forum without doing the background research that good governance demands. You are asking the wrong question in the wrong forum. The issue is not how to secure WordPress. It is how to provide “seamless” yet “secure” service-the buzzword is “identity and access management (IAM)”. I suggest that you spend 10 minutes Googling on “how to provide seamless yet secure access to online data” and you will understand why security, not WordPress, should be first concern.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred option is a quick-and-dirty, though very common, solution. The vendor has a "Support" page that contains limited "public" information. However the page includes a user "sign in" option so that authorised users can access all the "private" data that you have concerning your product.

This page can be accessed via the public website as well as via the  software (such as "Help > On-line Support").

You can be creative with the sign in details. The user name might be the licenced user name (which might be entered when the software is first installed). The password might be a code that is issued at the time of sale, but that is subject to a compulsory password change on first use, or even as part of a post-sales validation process. There are as many  options for sign in details as one's imagination can dream up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to avoid a password prompt for users.  The ideal solution is a seamless one without any prompts :)